# Cocos2D TouchesEnded not allowing me to access sprites?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, touchesbegan, touches

Thanks so much for reading!

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: [touch locationInView:touch.view]];
    CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(100, 120, 75, 113);

    int tjx = sprite.position.x;

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(myRect, location)) {
       tjx ++;            
    }
}
```

For some reason, `ccTouchesEnded` isn't allowing me to access my "sprite". I also tried to use 
`CGRectMake` like so :

```
CGRectMake( sprite.position.x, sprite.position.y, sprite.contentSize.Width, sprite.contentSize.Height)
```

But I couldn't access my sprites position or height. I keep getting "sprite" undeclared when it is declared in the init method, and added to the child.

Please help!! I'm sure i'm missing something really simple here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried,

- `[self sprite]`
- `self.sprite`
- Checked if sprite is declared as a property and have you synthesized it?

Comment: I used the Ktag method, and that fixed this issue. Thank you so much Rob!

Answer (score 0):

"sprite" is probably declared locally in init method but not a member of the class.

One solution would be to give sprite a tag:

```
sprite.tag = 123; // any arbitrary number to identify this sprite
```

Later on you can access that sprite by using:

```
CCSprite* sprite = [self getChildByTag:123];
```

It is similar to removing a child by tag:
http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/knowledge-base/cocos2d-iphone-faq/learn-cocos2d-public-content/manual/cocos2d-general/14824-how-to-remove-a-child-from-the-nodescenelayer